# RSpec match_array fail even when arrays are the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

**Note:** my app works just fine. I'm just unable to do the right rspec for it.

**trash_controller.rb:**

```
class TrashController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_slide, only: [ :show, :destroy, :restore ]

    def set_slide
        @trashed_slide = Slide.only_deleted.find(params[:id])
    end

    def show
    end
```

**trash_controller_spec.rb:**

```
describe TrashController do

  let(:album) { create(:album) }
  let(:slide) { build(:slide) }

  describe "GET #show" do
    before do
      slide.save
      slide.destroy        
      get :show, id: slide.id
    end

    it { expect(assigns(:trashed_slide)).to match_array(Slide.only_deleted.to_a) } 
  end
```

error:

```
1) TrashController GET #show should contain exactly #<Slide id: 1, album_id: 1, description: "Brennon Prosacco", created_at: "2014-04-02 06:06:03", updated_at: "2014-04-02 06:06:03", photo_file_name: "sample_2.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 204509, photo_updated_at: "2014-04-02 06:06:03", photo_fingerprint: "4dbd1870094527b8c4ddca6afd415eb9", deleted_at: "2014-04-02 06:06:03", photo_processing: false>
     Failure/Error: it { expect(assigns(:trashed_slide)).to match_array(Slide.only_deleted.to_a) }
       expected an array, actual collection was #<Slide id: 1, album_id: 1, description: "Brennon Prosacco", created_at: "2014-04-02 06:06:03", updated_at: "2014-04-02 06:06:03", photo_file_name: "sample_2.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 204509, photo_updated_at: "2014-04-02 06:06:03", photo_fingerprint: "4dbd1870094527b8c4ddca6afd415eb9", deleted_at: "2014-04-02 06:06:03", photo_processing: false>
     # ./spec/controllers/trash_controller_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't get what it's about as both lines looks the same. Any ideas ?

Comment: What's gonna happen if you remove `to_a` call?

Comment: Then nothing is shown after `1) TrashController GET #show should contain exactly` in its line. Rest are the same.

Comment: I assume that only_deleted is a scope, right? Could you show how is it defined and how trashed_slide is being assigned?

Comment: probably yes, as I was trying to read the code of [paranoid2 gem](https://github.com/anjlab/paranoid2). In my controler there's no more than empty `def show`. All the rest is set by the gem itself and `paranoid` in the model. I was wondering if it could be a problem for model rspec that `module Paranoid2
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern`.

Comment: Could you also show your `show` action?

Comment: I just updated the question with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect `Slide.only_deleted.find(params[:id])` to return an array. `find` returns just one slide. Therefore I would change the expectation to:

```
expect(assigns(:trashed_slide)).to eq(Slide.only_deleted.first)
```

Comment: worked like a charm ! Just one more question if I may. I think it should be somehow visible on the error message but even now I can't see anything what would suggest where's the problem. Am I missing something important there ?

Comment: The error descriptions says: `expected an array, actual collection was #<Slide id: 1...` If there was an array returned there would have been a `[` in that message in front of the `#<Slide`. Hard to see that there is one character missing.